# How structure input boxes in tkinter dynamically?

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter, datastore

Hi I am currently designing some input boxes using tkinter on which the user will type info, but the problem is that those must be generated according to other variable. If the variable says three then there will be three input boxes, if it says 10 there must be 10 input boxes. Those input boxes must have a name or be stored as the GUI will use the values typed in the next process called by the user.

I am currently programming it in OOP, and I would like also an advice on how I could store the data typed on the input boxes.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os


class boxes():
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr=arr
        self.boxes=Tk()
        self.boxes.geometry('650x300')
        self.boxes.title('Welcome to the automated system')
        self.instructions=Label(self.boxes, text='Willkommen user, in this window you should type in the log file info')
        self.instructions.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 4)
        Label(self.boxes, text = "Zone name").grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(self.boxes, text = "Temperature").grid(row=1, column=1)
        Label(self.boxes, text = "Humidity").grid(row=1, column=2)
        Label(self.boxes, text = "Irradiance Start Wm2").grid(row=1, column=3)
        Label(self.boxes, text = "Irradiance End Wm2").grid(row=1, column=4)
        self.len=len(self.arr)
        self.counter=2
        self.matrix={}
        #for i in self.arr:
        #    self.matrix[i]={'Temperate':'','Humidity':'','Irradiance_0':'','Irradiance_t':''}
        for i in self.arr:
            self.zone={}
            Label(self.boxes, text=i, relief=RIDGE, width=15).grid(row=self.counter, column=0)
            self.zone['Temperature_{0}'.format(i)]=Entry(self.boxes, width=20).grid(row=self.counter, column=1)
            self.zone['Humidity_{0}'.format(i)]=Entry(self.boxes, width=20).grid(row=self.counter, column=2)
            self.zone['Irradiance_0_{0}'.format(i)]=Entry(self.boxes, width=20).grid(row=self.counter, column=3)
            self.zone['Irradiance_1_{0}'.format(i)]=Entry(self.boxes, width=20).grid(row=self.counter, column=4)
            self.counter+=1
            self.matrix[i]=self.zone

        #self.read=Text(self.Prueba, height=2, width=30)
        #self.read.pack()
        self.start = Button(self.boxes, text='Ingest', command=self.matrix_log)  ###bg='#111', fg='white' for change in colors
        self.start.grid(row=self.len+2, column=0)
        self.cancel = Button(self.boxes, text='Cancel', command=self.close)  ###bg='#111', fg='white' for change in colors
        self.cancel.grid(row=self.len+2, column=1)
        self.boxes.mainloop()
    def matrix_log(self):
        for key, value in self.matrix.items():
            for data in value:
                print(data)
        print(self.matrix)


    def close(self):
        self.boxes.destroy()
  



prueba=boxes(['hola','ada','adsa'])
prueba
```

Comment: you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: why is ```self.arr``` a string and not an integer?

Comment: Hi, it is a list that comes from other iteration, it has to be string rather than integer cause every input box will have to be assigned to every element of the array, this array has some names and the user will have to type in the data of those names

Comment: Its not very clear what you want, could you edit the question with a [mcve] and explain in more detail?

Comment: `self.zone[...]=Entry(...).grid(...)` makes `self.zone[...]` as `None` because it is the result of `grid(...)`.  Use `self.zone[...]=Entry(...)` and `self.zone[...].grid(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks and thanks and many thanks to acw1668, it worked perfectly after putting grid in the next row, why this happens?  grid() isnt supposed to be a method for location rather than content?